# Manipulating two lists

Tags: python

I am trying to write the code such that, if `n[i+1]` is not equal to `n[i]`, then the `xmove` would be `m[i+1] - m[i]` else, if `n[i+1]` is equal to `n[i]`, then the `xmove` at that index is 0, while this continues till `n[i+1]` is not equal to `n[i`], then the `xmove` at that point is the difference between the first and the last `m` index while the equality condition exists. Same goes for the `ymove`. The output would be this

`xmove = [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1]`

`ymove = [1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1]`

Thank you

```
m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

n = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9]

xmove = []

ymove = []

first = []

Sum = []

for i in range(len(n)-1):

    if n[i+1] == n[1]:
        messi = 0
        xmove.append(messi)
        first.append(n[i])
        Sum.append(1)
        liit = sum(Sum)
        u = first[0] - liit
        xmove.append(u)
    else:
        u = n[i+1] - n[i]
        xmove.append(u)
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Are you sure `xmove` shouldn't be `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]`?

Comment: xmove[4] = 5 - 3 = 2. Thank you

Comment: @berhane167 But where do 5 and 3 come from?  if `i=4`, `m[4] - m[3] = 5 - 4 = 1` -- thats why I thought `xmove[4] = 1` -- can you clarify where you are getting the 3 from?

Comment: n[2] = n[3] = n[4], n[4] != n[5] therefore xmove = m[4] - m[2]. This has been the challenge. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification in comments -- what about something like:

```
m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
n = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9]

ind = range(len(n))

xeq = set()
yeq = set()

xmove = []
ymove = []
for (i,j) in zip(ind[:-1], ind[1:]):
    # Handle xmove (based on n) ------------------------------------------------
    if n[i] != n[j]:
        if not xeq:
            xe = m[j] - m[i]
        else:
            xe = m[max(xeq)] - m[min(xeq)]
            xeq.clear()
    else:
        xe = 0
        xeq.update([i,j])
    xmove.append(xe)

    # Handle ymove (based on m) ------------------------------------------------
    if m[i] != m[j]:
        if not yeq:
            ye = n[j] - n[i]
        else:
            ye = n[max(yeq)] - n[min(yeq)]
            yeq.clear()
    else:
        ye = 0
        yeq.update([i,j])
    ymove.append(ye)



print xmove, xmove == [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1]
print ymove, ymove == [1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1] True
[1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1] True
```

Or using a function:

```
def get_moves(a, b):
    ind = range(len(a))
    eq = set()
    moves = []
    for (i,j) in zip(ind[:-1], ind[1:]):
        if b[i] != b[j]:
            e = a[j] - a[i] if not eq else a[max(eq)] - a[min(eq)]
            eq.clear()
        else:
            e = 0
            eq.update([i,j])
        moves.append(e)
    return moves

m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
n = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9]

xmove = get_moves(m,n)
ymove = get_moves(n,m)

print xmove, xmove == [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1]
print ymove, ymove == [1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1] True
[1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1] True
```